# How to push order to paypal to get paid for pending orders : Magento

Tags: payment-methods, payment, order-status, magento-1.5

I am using PayPal express checkout on magento store. For some reason it was switched to sandbox and some customer put an order through this sandbox account so the orders are placed but no amount is received in actual pay pal account. Now I just want to know is there any way to push the orders to completed and get paid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Once an order is placed, you can't reconcile payment by some method other than what was actually given. If funds weren't captured, you could edit the order and enter new payment info at that point--but that won't give you a customer's PayPal Express account.

Your best bet is to cancel or offline-refund (credit memo) the bad order, and contact the customer to explain the situation and have them re-place it.

Unrelated, Magento CE 1.5 is very old now. I would strongly recommend updating to the latest M1 release (currently 1.9), or at the very least ensuring you are up to date on security patches.